# flex air httpservice stream error and timing out

Tags: apache-flex, air, timeout, httpservice

We have an AIR client sending HTTPService Post request to Tomcat. The operation takes more than 30 seconds in the server since its a files transfer operation.

By the time the server returns the response, Flex is throwing a fault, 2032, stream error ( checked a lot on the net ) Looks like its timing out after 30 seconds, waiting for the Http response.

i tried setting ht.requestTimeout, it did not work. Setting URLRequestDefaults.idleTimeout also is not working. Looks like i have hit a dead end on this.

Solutions please...

Comment: Is the flex request timing out; or is the server request timing out?

Comment: Its on the Air side. We have set a large timeout on Tomcat. The client shows a stream error, 2032 after 30 seconds. tried upgrading to latest AIR. Didn't help. This is critical and we need to fix it. Please let me know if there is a way out...

Comment: I'm not sure; I know I've had longer requests (~1 minute) using AMF without timeouts.  Hopefully someone else more knowledgeable can chime in.

Comment: @Vish I encountered same problem. Were you able to resolve the issue? My air client fails because of the request time out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase [HTTPService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#requestTimeout) timeout using property [requestTimeout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#requestTimeout)

> Provides access to the request timeout in seconds for sent messages. A
>   value less than or equal to zero prevents request timeout.

you could also use its [fault](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#event%3afault) event to catch timeout, and proceed accordingly.

Hope that Helps

Comment: Setting the HTTPService timeout, requestTimeout has no effect. We have tried that many times with various values. It just times out after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I've been fighting this issue as well.  Add this code snippet before you send() your request:

```
URLRequestDefaults.idleTimeout = 120000;  // in millis so this setting would timeout after 120 seconds.
```

It seems as though there's a bug in the Flash Player for AIR (Flex uses a different one) that ignores responseTimeout on the HTTPRequest object.  This sets the timeout properly.