# How to increase air client http request time out?

Tags: apache-flex, air, timeout, httprequest, http-request

There was a similar question asked long time ago([flex air httpservice stream error and timing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295537/flex-air-httpservice-stream-error-and-timing-out)), but I didn't see an answer. I am using air SDK3.1 and need to increase air client request time out due to long processing time of the server. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Request time out is a [server side setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145131/tomcat-request-timeout). You need to setup the time out on your server. Again this is server specific. It could be anywhere.

Also you can try to set [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#requestTimeout) to value less than 0. Some one has this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15715794/258741).